Articles in the poem “Nothing Gold Can Stay”
Why in the following poem are no articles in the 5th line?
Nature’s first green is gold,
Her hardest hue to hold. 
Her early leaf’s a flower; 
But only so an hour.
 Then leaf subsides to leaf. 
So Eden sank to grief, 
So dawn goes down to day.
 Nothing gold can stay.


(1) Poetry doesn't always have to be in grammatical sentences.
(2) We do, in fact, sometimes use nouns without an article to indicate that one follows another in a long succession.

They waited hour by hour for news.


If in a scientific book an author will write “photon subsides to photon” will it be grammatically correct?

Not sure what "subsides" would mean in a photon context. Except perhaps if they were falling into a black hole.  But it's grammatical.
